# How to alter the snippet below to fetch the second value in between the delimeters?

Tags: php, regex

How to alter the snippet below to fetch the first and second value in between the delimeters?

Output Example: First value: `9100450` and second value: `HHkk` based on the `searchfor` value: `12348888`

```php
$input = '0123456|BHKAHHHHkjkjkjkjk|12345678|JuiKKK121255
    9100450|HHkk|12348888|JuiKKK10000000021sdadad255';
$searchfor = '12348888';
$regexp = "/(?<=" . $searchfor . "\\|)\\w+/m";
$result = preg_match_all($regexp, $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
$regexp = "/^([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|" . $searchfor . "\|/m";
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/gYhLW) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NhzOdG/1). *Details*:

- `^` - (here, due to `m`) start of a line
- `([^|]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than a `|` char
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `([^|]+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than a `|` char
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `12348888` - some hard-coded value
- `\|` - a `|` char.

If your `$searchfor` value can contain special chars, replace `$searchfor` with `preg_quote($searchfor, '/')` in the code.

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/fM0Hv):

```php
$input = '0123456|BHKAHHHHkjkjkjkjk|12345678|JuiKKK121255
9100450|HHkk|12348888|JuiKKK10000000021sdadad255';
$searchfor = '12348888';
$regexp = "/^([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|" . $searchfor . "\|/m";
if (preg_match($regexp, $input, $match)) {
    $val1 = $match[1];
    $val2 = $match[2];
    echo "$val1\n$val2";
}
```